# Comma before "that": OLD vs. MW

Tags: commas, non-restrictive

The meaning for *bassinet* in Oxford Learner's Dictionaries reads:

> a small bed for a baby, that looks like a basket

while that in Merriam Webster Learner's Dictionary reads:

> a small bed for a baby that looks like a basket and that usually has a hood or cover over one end

Is the comma before "that" in OLD deliberate? Is there any grammatical explanation for this?

Comment: OLD is precluding the suggestion that it is the baby rather than the bed which looks like a basket.

Comment: Oh @StoneyB -aby, you got that right! So MW is focused on the baby. Thank god for the second *that*, or the baby would also have got a hood or cover.

Comment: Arun, you could @MerriamWebster this I guess.

Comment: It is very important to make sure you keep one end of the baby covered.

Comment: @Kris: This is what I received as a reply from Merriam-Webster: "The Learner’s Dictionary is written with deliberately simpler language than is found in the Collegiate Dictionary, due to its being intended for readers for whom English is not their first language. Sometimes this does result in indirect phrasings that could be interpreted in a way different from what is intended, but given the context regarding the definition for bassinet, it would seem to be logical to read "bed for a baby" as a single idea and understand that it is the bed, and not the baby, that looks like a basket."

Comment: Ah! So, that answers the Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Learner’s Dictionary is written with deliberately simpler language than is found in the Collegiate Dictionary, due to its being intended for readers for whom English is not their first language. Sometimes this does result in indirect phrasings that could be interpreted in a way different from what is intended, but given the context regarding the definition for bassinet, it would seem to be logical to read "bed for a baby" as a single idea and understand that it is the bed, and not the baby, that looks like a basket.